# Phasing website directory/ folder name vb.net

Tags: vb.net, web, url, directory, uri

I have a website with folders i want vb.net to phase (check) for existance of these. Obviously if Directory exists dosnt work in this scenario so I came up with the following code.

```
     Dim PhaseUri As New System.Uri(http://www.example.com/My_Folder)
                    Dim PhaseURL As String = PhaseUri.Host.ToString

                    If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable AndAlso My.Computer.Network.Ping(PhaseURL, 1000) Then
Else
End If
```

The code checks if [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) exists by extracting it from the entire (http://www.example.com/My_Folder), its as close as I can get, however if [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) exists but My_Folder dosnt then I have a problem. Basicaly my above code gets me as close as possible and then makes a short leap of faith in assuming the rest will also exist.

How can I phase/ validate/ check for the existance of the entier http://www.example.com/My_Folder using less than 100,000 lines and as minimal complex code as possible?

Comment: You could make a HEAD request, but the Server must respond to that kind of requests, the Directory listing must be enabled or the directory contains a default document. Otherwise, you'll get an exception even if the directory exists. If you have FTP access, you can request Directory listing (`NLIST` or `LIST`) and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

It only works if your 'folder' is a webpage or contains a default document.

**Works for a page, not folder**

```
public function IsFolderOnline(url as string) as boolean
    try
        dim wc as new system.net.webclient()
        wc.downloadstring(url)
        return true
    catch ex as exception
        return false
    end try
end function
```

use it like this:

```
dim IsItOnline as boolean = IsFolderOnline("http://example.org/folder")
```

**it is not possible to get all pages within a folder**

you must check every page for href elements to find new urls. It will only find urls that have a weblink.

Webclient.Downloadstring() downloads the html of a page.

use this code to retrieve all urls from the page

```
  ' Finding urls in the page
    Dim FoundUrls As New List(Of String)

    Dim strRegex As String = "<a[^<>]*>"
    Dim myRegex As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(strRegex, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None)
    For Each myMatch As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In myRegex.Matches(html)
        If myMatch.Success Then
            Dim strRegex2 As String = "href=""[^""]*"""
            Dim myRegex2 As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(strRegex, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None)
            For Each myMatch2 As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In myRegex.Matches(myMatch.Value)
                If myMatch2.Success Then
                    Dim value As String = Split(Split(myMatch2.Value, """", 2).Last, """", 2).First

                    If value.ToLower.StartsWith("http://" & DomainName.ToLower) Then
                        FoundUrls.Add(value)
                    End If

                    If value.ToLower.StartsWith("https://" & DomainName.ToLower) Then
                        FoundUrls.Add(value)
                    End If


                    If value.ToLower.StartsWith("/") Then
                        FoundUrls.Add(Protocol & DomainName & value)
                    Else
                        If Not value.Contains(":") Then
                            FoundUrls.Add(Protocol & DomainName & "/" & value)
                        End If
                    End If


                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

**you might want to remove links that contain files**

```
  'Remove unsupported urls
        Dim UnsupportedExtensions() As String = {".css", ".ico", ".xml", ".axd", ".js", ".zip", ".rar", ".7z", ".tar", ".jar", ".pdf", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp", ".mp4", ".mov", ".mpeg", ".gif"}
        For Each url In FoundUrls.ToList
            For Each UnsupportedExtension In UnsupportedExtensions
                If url.ToLower.EndsWith(UnsupportedExtension) Then
                    FoundUrls.Remove(url)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
```